# Small and cheap pcb-to-pcb connection

Tags: pcb, connector, pcb-assembly

I'm looking for a smart way to connect two PCB's in a cheap manner. I would prefer not to use any external components for the connection (if possible).

The PCB's are rather small (20 x 20 mm).

Do you have any idea?

Best Regards,
Andreas

[image: Illustration of PCB-to-PCB connection scenario]

Comment: Permanent joint, or disconnectable?  Rigid, or flexible, or don't care?

Comment: This is routinely done with a piece of solid-core ribbon cable. However, for quantities more than a few, stripping of ribbon cable requires a special tool.

Comment: @venny that is a good option, if you need a permanent connection and don't mind a flexible joint, a ribbon cable is an excellent option.

Answer (score 4):

If you need a permanent joint, and you need this to be mass-produced, but you care about space (no room for a connector) or cost (connector is too expensive), you could use [hot bar soldering](http://www.flexdude.com/Back%20Issues/FCN11-00A.PDF).

The idea is that a flat cable (usually a special kind of flex pcb) is pressed down by the hot bar so that it makes all the connections at once.

Example: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/3098/26394

If you can overlap the boards (ie: they don't absolutely have to connect edge to edge like puzzle pieces, but the edges can overlap like shingles), you could use [z-axis adhesive](https://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/company-us/all-3m-products/~/3M-Electrically-Conductive-Adhesive-Transfer-Tape-9703/?N=5002385+3294001720&rt=rud).

Answer (score 2):

What do you consider "External"? Usually this type of connection is called "Card-edge", and it uses a special socket mounted on one of the boards, and the other board has pads located just perfectly on the edge of the PCB. The most common use I have seen is PCI-e connectors in computers. The cards have pads on them and the motherboard has the connectors.

[image]

That's really your best option. I wouldn't try connecting bare PCBs together, there would be a lot of stress on the joint and you might rip up pads.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DB-25 plug and a DB-25 socket.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-subminiature

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you're designing a jigsaw like electronics kit. In that case try (1) right-angled pin-headers - pins on one side and sockets on the other both lying parallel to the PCBs. They may take up too much PCB area though, given the 20 x 20 mm dimensions.

Any standard edge connector will get in the way of the interlocking bumps on the PCBs.